# Install command line nuget on Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, mono

This may be more appropriate for StackOverflow, but I need to be able to compile my mono application on an Ubuntu server via ssh. I would like to have nuget restore my packages. There are several [tutorials](https://monomvc.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/nuget-on-mono/) available to make that possible, but all seem to assume access to a GUI. I know very little about linux, this is basically my first project. I don't see an apt package that I can install. Tutorials seem to require downloading the command line utility from a website. is there some way with a url I can do this via the command line? if so, where should put the files? Is there a better way than this and all the pages I'm finding are old? (I did install mono-complete and it doesn't appear to include nuget as was suggested on one site I visited.)

Comment: Try this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nuget (for 15.04 and up)